# Why does Jdownloader refuse to open?

Tags: jdownloader

I've just install **jdownloader** but i do not understand how it works.
If I add it click on the **jdownloader** icon, nothing happens.

I installed this way

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jd-team/jdownloader
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jdownloader
```

In terminal I get this:

```
/home/user/.jdownloader/config/PACKAGEMANAGER.cfg (No such file or directory)
```

in `/home/`**`[MyUserName]`**`/.jdownloader`, I can see a `jdupdate.jar` but no `/config/PACKAGEMANAGER.cfg`

I have Java 6.26 installed.

one month later and several extra hours lost, I still haven't managed to install JDownloader on my Ubuntu 11.10

It seems all the tutorials are outdated ! Did somebody manage ?

Note : it took me less than 5 mn to install on OSX. What the hell with Ubuntu ?

Comment: ... you open it, then copy the link you want to download.. and start the download in jdownloader.. what you don't undertsand?.

Comment: i click on it but it does not open !

Comment: click on what? a link, jdownloader?.. what?

Comment: I click on the jdownloader icon in the unity dash

Comment: Have you installed Java? try to run it from a terminal and see what errors you get ,i must that i too experienced this and was forced to use the jdownlaoder.jar file 'cause the executable wouldn't load.

Comment: Yes, **java 6.26**

Comment: in terminal I get this :
/home/user/.jdownloader/config/PACKAGEMANAGER.cfg (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to install jdownloader.
this post helped me.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/87342/alternative-to-downloading-files-through-firefox

Answer (score 2):

Based on your last comment (you may add it to your initial question - just click the edit link below the [jdownloader](/questions/tagged/jdownloader) tag), i assume jdownloader isn't configured properly. It obviously tries to access

`/home/user/.jdownloader/config/PACKAGEMANAGER.cfg`,

but it should try to access

`/home/`**`[YourUserName]`**`/.jdownloader/config/PACKAGEMANAGER.cfg`

EDIT: If you install jdownloader using ther [jdownloader ppa](https://launchpad.net/~jd-team/+archive/jdownloader), jdownloader first tries to update itself to the newest version. You get more information about what's going on if you start `jdownloader` from the command line using `jdownloader -v`.

I myself didn't get the PPA version to run on my own PC (Ubuntu 10.04), so it seems to be a bug (jdownloader wasn't able to update itself). I recommend installing JDownloader manually, by downloading the LInux installation file from JDownloader's download page.

Comment: yes, I got Jdownloader from the PPA, I'll try to load this week end manually from jdownloader site.Seams to be not so easy, it says I must install WGET before downloading !

Comment: @tohuwawohu can you please edit this answer a step by step guide in installing Jdownloader manually?

Comment: @Mysterio: i discourage **strongly** from installing jDownloader manually. There are far too many pitfalls that may lead to disappointment. Instead, i **strongly** recommend to check the different download managers that are available in the standard Ubuntu repositories: for example, `fatrat`, `kget` (for KDE / Kubuntu), `steadyflow` (for Gnome) and `uget`. Those applications are far more easy to install, and i assume that they (almost the "bigger" ones, fatrat or steadyflow) offer the same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove your home jdownloader profile and restart the program to see if it's a corrupt file and rebuilding it sves the problem.

Comment: Profile removal did not solve the issue